# What is the * used for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What does the * do before 'test' in the below code and across the Ruby programming language?

```
  def sample (*test)
       puts "The number of parameters is #{test.length}"
       for i in 0...test.length
          puts "The parameters are #{test[i]}"
       end
    end
    sample "Zara", "6", "F"
    sample "Mac", "36", "M", "MCA"
```

Answer (score 7):

The last parameter of a method may be preceded by an asterisk(*), which is sometimes called the 'splat' operator. This indicates that more parameters may be passed to the function. Those parameters are collected up and an array is created.

Example:

```
def sample (*test)
    puts test
end
```

And call it with:

```
sample(1,2,3)
```

Will return array: `[1,2,3]`

```
irb(main):001:0> def s(*t)
irb(main):002:1> puts t
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> s(1,2,3)
1
2
3
=> nil
```

Comment: It's documented here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array%2FHash+Argument

Comment: Use `p` instead of `puts` to make the output more readable and less ambiguous, since it will print `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Note that in latest versions of ruby, it doesn't have to be the last parameter... `(*items, var)` works and assigns all arguments but the last to `items` array and assigns the last to `var`... similarly you can have embedded... `(first_var, *items, last_var)` which assigns first argument to `first_var`, last argument to `last_var` and all arguments between first and last to the `items` array.

Answer (score 2):

OxAX mentioned one good use of the * prefix operator - [to collect arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array%2FHash+Argument) and this is what it does in your example.

```
def lots_of_args *args
  p args
end
lots_of_args 1,2,3 # => [1, 2, 3]

first, *rest = 1, 2, 3, 4
first # => 1
rest  # => [2, 3, 4]
```

We can even apply it outside of method definitions.

---

However, it's important to note that there's another good use for it:

```
def add_three_nums a, b, c
  a + b + c
end

add_three_nums *[1,2,3]  # => 6
# same as calling "add_three_nums 1,2,3"
```

Essentially, the `*` operator expands a method argument that's an array into a list of arguments.

---

There's even a third use case:

```
first, *rest = [1, 2, 3, 4]
first # => 1
rest  # => [2, 3, 4]
```

This third case is somewhat similar to the first. However, notice that we get the values of `first` and `rest` from an array, not from a list of values.

---